# How do I recognize the most important key or changing points in an audio file?

Tags: audio, python, audio-processing

I would like to analyse a wav audio file and determine the key passages of the song using python.

To do this, I have so far first analysed the root mean square and then formed the derivative, which leads to an array with around 15000 values. I thought that I could determine the key points by finding the values of the array that stand out particularly strongly from the other values. However, since I want to use the algorithm for more than just a single song, I cannot simply specify how many of these points should be found, since each song has a different number of potential key points. It must also be considered that it may happen that within an extremely short period of time, several strongly salient values would have to be combined into one key point, depending on the context of the song.

So far I have tried to solve this with np.std() and take the values that are greater than np.std(). However, I get far too many values. To limit this, I have combined the values into blocks, which are then iterated over and it is determined for each one whether it is greater than np.std(). If it is, it is added to a list and if not, 0 is added in its place. Then the size of the blocks is halved and the whole thing is done in the blocks that were previously larger than np.std() until a block consists of a single value. This worked quite well, except that after a certain small number of values per block, important key points that were previously recognised are suddenly no longer recognised and are therefore missing. How can I either make it so that these are no longer missing or that I filter out the particularly outstanding values directly?

Comment: What are you referring to as “*key points*”?

Comment: @Jdip Especially the parts of the song where it goes from a break to a drop or from a drop to a break for example. Sorry, I should have make this a little bit more clear.

Comment: I don't have much experience in this kind of "higher level" processing but I believe that one single value is not adequate to describe something that is conceptually complex. Taking an example from the Machine Learning field, you'll see that in order to reach a conclusion about something conceptually complex (being a vowel, a change in key during a song or something similar) a lot of information is used in the form of features. I believe that your best be would be to try and find meaningful features that (somehow) incorporate the information you seek and use them accordingly.

Comment: if you start listening to a bunch of songs and counting beats you might come to the conclusion that every 32 beats in every song there will be a changing point :)

Comment: Is this audio a single voice or single instrument (those are easier to do pitch detection with) or is it a complete mix?  Polyphonic, lotsa voices.

Answer (score 0):

Start with clean definition of what exactly you want. Take a handful of "representative" songs and mark them up by hand. Define clearly WHY you mark them as "key points".

Most songs can be broken down in different parts (intro, verse, bridge, chorus, solo, outro, etc.) which are repeated in varying order. Most musicians would probably use these to define the "key points".

These are not easy to find. Your best shot is to look for repeated pattern of chord progressions and figure out for each pattern what the lead instrument (voice, guitar, saxophone, etc). This being said, chords are not easy to recognize.

One place to start is analyzing the time domain pattern. Most music is written in bars of 3 or 4 beats/bar and than each part of the song has often 4, 8 or 16 bars.